# Is it possible to get the values from Json object with limit

Tags: java, json, postgresql, jackson

I have a Json object like this in my Postgres DB:

```
{
"emails": [
{
"email": {
"id": "e8dc927f-679d-496b-85fb-465edf35c676",
"value": "hello@gmail.com"
}
},
{
"email": {
"id": "1b78758a-abc4-46ef-9de9-c999a0c8c418",
"value": "hello1@gmail.com"
}
}
],
"lastName": {
"id": "718109fd-2d00-475a-829a-c8af9a7f0067",
"value": "lastName"
},
"firstName": {
"id": "6c46a5b3-6f89-4692-a214-4943de22018d",
"value": "firstName"
},
}
```

And so on big json with around 1000 elements, now I want to parse and get the first 500 elements from json and make another json. what I mean by element here is anything which has Id is a element. For example firstName , LastName, email, email are the elements not the emails. I tried Jackson api but couldn't find a way how to count the elements and make a json exactly like above and return. and when I do any modifications in the first 500 elements I should save the Json with edits. Any help is much appreciated. I even tried postgres **array_agg(e)** function but that is only accepting only array.

Comment: Do you want a SQL solution (=Postgres) or a Java solution (=Jackson)

Comment: anything should be fine, if it is DB which give me performance that will be more helpful

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, any help?